# Command line arguments, reading a file

Tags: c, file, arguments, command-line-arguments

If i entered into the command line
C: myprogram myfile.txt

How can I use myfile in my program. Do I have to scanf it in or is there an arbitrary way of accessing it.

My question is how can I use the myfile.txt in my program.

```
int
main(){
    /* So in this area how do I access the myfile.txt 
    to then be able to read from it./*
```

Comment: You open it with `fopen()` or `open()`.

Comment: Is your question about how to read files, or about how to get the filename from the argument list?

Comment: Note that if you're on a unix-like system you could run your program as `myprogram < myfile` and the contents of the file will be fed into stdin.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use `int main(int argc, char **argv)` as your main function.

`argc` - will be the count of input arguments to your program.
`argv` - will be a pointer to all the input arguments.

So, if you entered `C:\myprogram myfile.txt` to run your program:

- `argc` will be 2
- `argv[0]` will be `myprogram`.
- `argv[1]` will be `myfile.txt`.

More details [can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024197/what-does-int-argc-char-argv-mean)

To read the file:
`FILE *f = fopen(argv[1], "r"); // "r" for read`

For opening the file in other modes, [read this](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html).

Comment: How to pass the `txt` file name to another function, not to the `main`?

Answer (score 4):

1. Declare your main like this

   `int main(int argc, char* argv [])`

   - argc specified the number of arguments (if no arguments are passed it's equal to 1 for the name of the program)
   - argv is a pointer to an array of strings (containing at least one member - the name of the program)
   - you would read the file from the command line like so: `C:\my_program input_file.txt`
2. Set up a file handle:

   `File* file_handle;`
3. Open the file_handle for reading:

   `file_handle = fopen(argv[1], "r");`

   - fopen returns a pointer to a file or `NULL` if the file doesn't exist. argv[1](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/), contains the file you want to read as an argument
   - "r" means that you open the file for reading (more on the other modes [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/))
4. Read the contents using for example [fgets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/):

   `fgets (buffer_to_store_data_in , 50 , file_handle);`

   - you need a `char *` buffer to store the data in (such as an array of chars), the second argument specifies how much to read and the third is a pointer to a file
5. Finally close the handle

   `fclose(file_handle);`

All done :)

Answer (score 3):

This is the Programming 101 way. It takes a lot for granted, and it doesn't do any error-checking at all! But it will get you started.

```
/* this has declarations for fopen(), printf(), etc. */
#include <stdio.h>

/* Arbitrary, just to set the size of the buffer (see below).
   Can be bigger or smaller */
#define BUFSIZE 1000

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /* the first command-line parameter is in argv[1] 
       (arg[0] is the name of the program) */
    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r"); /* "r" = open for reading */

    char buff[BUFSIZE]; /* a buffer to hold what you read in */

    /* read in one line, up to BUFSIZE-1 in length */
    while(fgets(buff, BUFSIZE - 1, fp) != NULL) 
    {
        /* buff has one line of the file, do with it what you will... */

        printf ("%s\n", buff); /* ...such as show it on the screen */
    }
    fclose(fp);  /* close the file */ 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Command line arguments are just plain C-strings. You can do whatever you want with them. In your case you might want to open a file, read something from it and close it.

You might find this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130375/how-exactly-does-fopen-fclose-work) (and answer) useful.

Answer (score 0):

All the suggestion you received about using the command line are correct,but
It sounds to me you can also consider to use a typical pattern that is read the `stdin` instead of a file, then drive your app by piping, for example cat `myfile > yourpgm`.
You then can use `scanf` to read from the stdin.
In an analogous way you can use `stdout/stderr` to produce the output.